# Should I mark this question as duplicate?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

Recently I've come across [quite a sophisticated question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358030) about color blending. It's already three years old, and for some reason it has comparatively many upvotes. I posted my own answer to it, and right after that I found that there is [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33358248/use-colormatrix-or-hexcolor-in-blendmodefilter-android) from the same author that was asked 30 minutes after the first (Oct 27 2015 at 0:35 vs Oct 27 2015 at 0:57).

I tend to think that they both were asked within the same problem, and my answer should help for both cases, so I'd like to mark second question as a duplicate of first. However I cannot be certain about that because the original question is somewhat vague and doesn't have the same amount of details as the second one. [The author](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2534694/zen) himself doesn't seem to be any more interested in it, since a lot of time passed and he logged in the last time more than a year and a half ago, so I don't believe he will ever accept my answer. However writing this answer took me quite a lot of effort, and I would like to point people to my findings somehow.

Comment: Maybe see if they could be merged? Looks like one question has a better answer but the other one is a better question

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with the topic matter to decide if this is entirely feasible, but how about deleting your current answer and posting it to the other question instead, then marking the one you originally answered as a duplicate.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

We need high quality questions and answers on the site, so you should add your answer to the better quality question and vote/flag to close the other question as a duplicate.

The other question can still exist as a signpost because not everyone is going to use the same terminology when searching for solutions to their problem so having several signposts to the correct answer(s) is beneficial to all.

Comment: For the sake of consistency, i don't thing the second question is better - it has more details, but they are specific to the case. I consider marking second question a duplicate OR adding another answer with more narrow scenario for the second one.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind if they're sufficiently different to have distinct answers that's fine too. Don't just copy paste the same answer onto both questions.