# Is it okay to edit questions marked as duplicate?

Tags: support, edits

I edited a question, placing code into a code block before I saw that the question was marked as a duplicate. Is it okay to do this or should questions marked as duplicates not be edited?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Please don't do this if you don't have edit privileges (less than 2000 rep). Because without them, you are only creating extra edit review work for other users, on something that's closed anyway.

Otherwise, there's nothing preventing you from editing closed posts.

Comment: Also, my understanding is a question will enter review queues because of an edit only once. So if the OP actually comes with a good edit afterwards, you may be blocking that from sending the proposed dupe in the review queue

Comment: @Patrice only if the question was closed recently.

Comment: When I'm googling I find the answer to a lot of my questions on posts marked as duplicate. I disagree that its "only creating extra edit review work". There can be some merit to editing duplicate posts since there are some which are really popular or otherwise useful for others trying to find the answer to their question (myself included)

Comment: @chevybow but If you find the super in your Google search and the dupe closure was appropriate, you can follow the dupe to get the answer you need. I am not certain how editing dupes changes that....

Comment: @Patrice There are some questions where the linked duplicate doesn't have nearly as detailed or helpful answers at the one marked as duplicate... For example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-do-i-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript

Comment: @chevybow then thats a poorly handled duplicate. Again, I don't see how an edit changes that. If they truly are dupes, the answers should be kept on the best question. Editing one of the dupes won't solve that. Or I'm really misunderstanding what you intend the edit to do...

Comment: @Braiam is it really time based? I thought it was "only if the question hadn't been edited since then".

Comment: @Kaiido yes, it is. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078

Answer (score 48):

It depends on how good the post is.

If the duplicate is so poor (due to lack of research, the question is unclear, or another reason that will lead to it being deleted), then there's probably no reason to clean it up. As a general rule, [we don't polish crap](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/274286/7795130), since that effort will be wasted when the post is deleted anyways. By editing it, you waste your own time, plus the time of reviewers who have to look at it.

However, duplicates can be good [signposts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/377796/7795130) for people searching for the same thing with distinct terminology. These duplicates are important to keep around, and anything we're keeping on the site should be in the best conditions possible. So please do edit any good duplicates, because they can be and often are useful.

If it's somewhere in between, you might be able to make the duplicate into a better signpost with your edit. If you can, go for it, and make sure to leave a specific edit reason so that the reviewers know why you're modifying the wording as you are. Make sure not to deviate from the author's intent though, you should be clarifying what's there to make it a better duplicate.

Comment: An important distinction here is that questions closed as duplicates are never deleted by the system, so at least *that* part of the argument against wasting effort does not hold.

Comment: @TylerH are you sure? I don't remember seeing different Roomba rules for duplicates than regular no-answer with downvotes (https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367653/update-roomba-help-page-with-changes-for-duplicate-questions)

Comment: nope. duplicate with answers don't roomba. read the answer again. I have edited it for more clarity

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Yeah, I should clarify. The `RemoveAbandonedClosed` reason will never apply to questions closed as duplicates. Such questions *can* get deleted under the `RemoveDeadQuestions` or `RemoveAbandonedQuestions`, but only if they meet the criteria. As Jean-Francois indicates, such a question is impervious to auto-deletion if it has an answer, or if it has 2+ comments, or has a score of 1+, etc.

Answer (score 6):

[Other answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/381031/6451573) already explained that you should not create work in the edit queue, but even if you have more than 2000 reputation (which allow to skip the edit queue), you'll create work by editing the question in the *reopen queue* [if you edit it in the 5 day period after closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078)

People who closed as duplicate (gold badge, or several people) can edit the question without it to be placed in the queue. Those people, by doing this, are improving the signpost.

Original poster can edit the question with more details explaining why it's not a duplicate, and the question usefully hits the reopen queue in that case too.

But you probably don't have enough information to do the same and have it reopened.

So others will have to review your changes and understand that they should *not* vote to reopen. If you really need to do this to improve a good signpost, you should use an explicit edit comment like "clarification, but still duplicate" so people don't reopen, but I would advise against it, maybe comment/ping the people who closed so they can do it themselves without the question hitting the reopen queue.

Comment: As I understand it, closed questions only enter the re-open queue upon editing if they were closed less than five days ago.

Comment: @halfer he doesn't need to agree. Shog says it is https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196074/lots-of-questions-in-the-reopen-queue/196078#196078

Comment: @Braiam: thanks. I just like to make sure `:-)`, I am frequently wrong!

Answer (score 1):

My policy is that you should wait until you have 2K reputation, since closed questions are less in need of editing than open ones. It is also best to avoid editing questions that were closed less than five days ago, as that will cause the question to enter the Reopen Queue (of course this is fine if you think your edit will help the question reopen).

We do not have the tools or delete-voters to get rid of many deletable questions, and there is some disagreement on what constitutes a deletable question. One popular view, which I subscribe to up to a point, is that some closed (duplicate) questions can be signposts to existing (canonical) solutions. Thus, for good or bad, Stack Overflow will always carry a large number of closed questions.

With all that in mind, I would argue that it is good to edit closed questions. Not only does this make signposts more readable, but it may serve to educate authors about the kind of quality we would like to see in their posts first time around.